# Why specifically mention Yosef?

Tags: names, eretz-yisrael, pinchas, mattos

When listing who will settle in land on the east of the Jordan river, Moshe adds in part of the tribe of Menashe, but Bamidbar 32:33 identifies the group as coming from the tribe of "Menashe ben Yosef." Parentage is not named elsewhere.

This method only exists in the 5 books in this discussion and the 2 mentions of the daughters of Tzelofchad though in those cases, it is called "mishpachat" whereas in 32:33 it is "shevet."

The only explanation I found was in the Birkat Asher who [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Birkat_Asher_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.32.33.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> רק תמוה שדווקא אצלם מוסיף הכתוב "בן יוסף", ושלא כאצל בני ראובן וגד, שאינם מיוחסים על שם אביהם, והרי יוסף מחובבי ארץ ישראל היה, והיה אפוא מקום שלא להזכיר שמו בקשר למעשה זה

This answer, identifying Yosef as different from others because he loved the land leads me to a number of questions, chief being

1. How do we know Yosef loved the land, especially more than Yaakov, the father of the other tribes involved?
2. Who are the other חובבי ארץ from among whom Yosef is found?
3. This construction is found in those 2 mentions of Tzelaphchad and once in Yehoshua. Do they show any specific love of the land that is unusual or distinctive (and why wouldn't this language be used in other situations regarding apportioning land?

[side note, and a confusing one -- Tzelaphchad wasn't the only spy who tried to enter the land against Moshe's wishes, which would show a love for the land. This is mentioned in [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.113?lang=bi) medrash after a statement by R. Yehudah Ben Beteira but Rashi mentions it [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.3?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he&p3=Shabbat.96a-96b&lang3=he) as stated by R. Shimon and it is sourced to a page in the gemara which, as far as I can see, at least online, does not quote that part of the medrash. E-daf doesn't seem to be working so I can't see if a printed version has the citation in Mas Shabbat 96b]

Comment: Yosef is the equivalent generational level to Reuven and Gad. Why wouldn't it mention him?

Comment: was there some other shevet menashe?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: So there is no reason to specify which Menashe is identified by calling "shevet". Is there some other need to identify by the people of one generation earlier? Is this done in other cases?

Comment: Aren’t all tribes identified by which son of Yaakov was the progenitor?

Comment: Not in (for example) Bam 1:35.

Comment: I only see the excerpt you quoted, no more, of the ברכת אשר, so I may well be getting this wrong, but I _think_ the stuff about יוסף's loving the land is part of the question rather than, as you read it, an answer.

Comment: @msh210 I'm not sure -- the grammar of the statement made it unclear to me if he was reinforcing his question or presenting an answer. Anyone with a solid understanding of the structure should please enlighten me!